# How to disable a windows service with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, service

I know how to use `win32serviceutil` to start, stop, and restart services, but how can I disable them, or set them on manual start? I'm fine with using any module compatible with Python 3.4.

Comment: You can use the [`PyWin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32) library. Here's a [link to the documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html) where you can find a bunch of methods regarding services.

Comment: @Cyber Sorry, I can't seem to find it. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Disable is one of windows service startup types. And it's different from normal windows service operations, such as start, stop, restart and so on.

You need to use `--startup disabled` as parameters for win32serviceutil. [Here](http://pyxr.sourceforge.net/PyXR/c/python24/lib/site-packages/win32/lib/win32serviceutil.py.html) is detail description. Check Usage() function.

After setting startup type, you need to stop the service. And after that, that service will be disabled unless you change the startup type again.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) is detail for windows service, if you find all detail about windows service startup type.

If this is the answer, please confirm it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `os.system` and Windows' `Sc.exe` to do it. Like so:

```
import os
os.system("sc config " + servicename + " start=disabled")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use **WMI**([Windows Management Instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page)) to disable the windows service with python module 'wmi'.

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
windows_update_services_list = [
    "wuauserv",
    "TrustedInstaller"
]

for service_name in windows_update_services_list:
    service = c.Win32_Service(Name=service_name)[0]
    service.ChangeStartMode(StartMode="Disabled")
```

other useful links:

- [win32-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-service)
- [change service start mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/changestartmode-method-in-class-win32-service)

powershell commands:

```
Set-Service -Name <service name> -StartupType Disabled
```